Convert List OR Array to Span
I'm working on an internal library that needs to support both lists and arrays. This is a hot path so we're looking at performance improvements.
Currently it's using IList<T> in the parameters, as we require index based access in the library, and to avoid re-writing it for both types.
public int Foo<T>(IList<T> values);

A pretty free performance improvement (measured and benchmarked) would be to convert it to a span internally, which we could do just by making some overloads that convert the value and pass it on immediately, but it feels like there should be a cleaner way. I'm not a big fan of having a lot of stubs, especially when it seems like they're doing a very similar thing.
public int Foo<T>(T[] values)
    => Foo(values.AsSpan());

public int Foo<T>(List<T> values)
    => Foo(CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(values));

private int Foo<T>(Span<T> values)

Is there any interface/marshal that can be used for both a List and an Array that converts them to a Span?

There is no way of using the same AsSpan() method for Lists and Arrays, other than creating your own AsSpan() Extension. Instead you could always use IList<T>:
public int Foo<T>(IList<T> list)
{   
    Span<T> span;

    if (list is T[] array)
    {
        span = array.AsSpan();
    }
    else if (list is List<T> concreteList)
    {
        span = CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(concreteList);
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("not supported!");
    }

    return Foo(span);
}

private int Foo<T>(Span<T> values)
{
    // ...
}


Yeah this is what we've landed on, just doesn't spark a huge amount of joy. Thanks!


A pretty free performance improvement

I wouldn't say it's really free. Maybe you should read the fine print on CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan<T>(List<T>)

Gets a Span<T> view over the data in a list. Items should not be
added or removed from the List<T> while the Span is in use.

This is due to the implementation (which really is the best anybody can do due to how List<T> is implemented):
T[] items = list._items; // this is the backing store of the list which could change if not enough capacity
...
span = new Span<T>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(items), size);

which really breaks the definition of what IList<T> is supposed to be able to do:
void Insert(int index, T item);
void RemoveAt(int index);

At this point we can think of IReadOnlyList<T> as a workaround, but this doesn't change the fact that while we are converting the List<T> instance to Span<T> inside the method (by getting a reference to the backing store of the list), somebody else could be changing the original List<T> to the point of having the need for a new backing store due to capacity limitations. Thus our method would be working on old / invalid / inconsistent data.
So, I would just add an overload accepting Span<T> for performance and do not do any changes in the existing method. Or if you really wanted to make it easier to people consuming the library maybe add:
/// <summary>
/// Some good warning...
/// </summary>
public int FooDangerous<T>(IList<T> values) {
    if (values is List<T> valuesList) {
        var span = CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan((List<T>)valuesList);
        return Foo(span);
    } else if (values is T[] valuesArray) {
        var span = valuesArray.AsSpan();
        return Foo(span);
    }
    // logic

}


That make sense, thanks. I was wondering why List<T> had a different mechanism for converting to a span than that used for an array.
In this context, we're always expecting collections to have all of their data (tbh they should probably be IReadOnlyList<T>), so it hadn't really crossed my mind about what would happen if the List was being modified elsewhere.
Thanks!

@JBrown521, yeah I think that's one of the (if not the main) reason why there isn't a convenient interface with GetSpan() added to the main collection/list BCL interfaces even though we had Span<T> for a long time now.
